# Unable to downgrade Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have Tensorflow 2 on my Mac but I need to downgrade it to 1.6.0 because I am using a package that needs that version of Tensorflow. I get the following error:

```
Collecting tensorflow==1.6.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.6.0 (from versions: 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.15.0rc0, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0rc3, 1.15.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0rc0, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.6.0
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: check your python version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you installing tensorflow? What command are you inputting? Try the below command:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.6.0
```